# Network request failed at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror in react native application(android)

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api, cloudinary

Getting the below error, while I'm trying to fetch the image list from cloudinary using fetch in react-native. How to resolve this?

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:441)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:567)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:397)
    at C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:503
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:179)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:351)
    at C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:116
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (C:\workspace\react_native\Gallery\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:115)
```

Comment: What is the code you are running that leads to this error?